# Выбор миниатюры фотографии на javascript

Tags: javascript, вконтакте

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать выбор миниатюры фотографии, как, например, вконтакте? Если можно, то приведите пример кода.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Когда то тоже нужно было что то подобное сделать, но нашел довольно таки хороший инструмент, называется cropper, там куда больше настроек чем в вк, так что думаю должно подойти ([GitHub](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper)), а так инструмент сам по себе называется "Crop Image".

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.